# Populating Array of arrays containing ref in Mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have in my schema an array of arrays containing ref. I want to populate the inside arrays which the arrays of _ids inside pairs
My schema looks like this:

```
var lunchBuddySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    pairs: [[{         
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }]],
});
```

I want to populate 'pairs'. When I push ID's into the pairs array I get something like this:

```
"pairs": [
    [
      "5b7484deff813ab2c0aa9a32",
      "5b74b49133027fba2c959379"
    ],
    [
      "5b75cab4e5953acb5e44d044",
      "5b75ca14e5953acb5e44d03f"
    ],
    [
      "5b65374a13c29342ae56d098",
      "5b73ba56bae5d9a21305993f"
    ],
    [
      "5b75ca48e5953acb5e44d041",
      "5b75ca6de5953acb5e44d042"
    ]
  ],
  "_id": "5b75f9a2040d9dd5e3f60979",
  "title": "Week 2",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Most of the time when I populate I use `exec.populate('pairs')` but in this case it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

populate({
        path: 'pairs',
        populate: { path: 'pairs' }
      });